# Resize iframe by dragging the bottom right corner

Tags: javascript

Is there any avaliable solution to iframe resizing? I am looking for something ready and tested.

Answer (score 1):

See jQuery's [UI/Resizeable](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Resizable). Not 100% sure if it works with iframe.